# Mod Portal 2 Audio

Tags: mods, portal-2

Okay so, I want to make an audio mod for Portal 2, but I'm not sure how to do it. I explored the game folder a bit but I couldn't find any distinct audio files (or at least in a format I would recognize). Does anyone have any pointers about how to do this? I'm sort of new to the world of computers, so I don't really know what all these files do, and I don't want to delete something important by accident. 
Thanks - DT75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portal 2 (and other Valve games) put their files in Valve Package (or [VPK](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/VPK)) files.

The Windows program [GCFScape](http://nemesis.thewavelength.net/?p=26) can be used to read these files, as can the command-line vpk program included in the Portal 2 Authoring Tools.

You can install the Portal 2 Authoring Tools from the Steam Library.  To find it, you will need to select Tools from the dropdown near the top of the library screen.

You will want to open the file whose name ends in `_dir.vpk`.  I think it's `pak01_dir.vpk` for Portal 2.

Basically, if you create sound files in the same path in Portal 2's `sound/` directory as they are inside the VPK files, the game will use these sound files in preference to the ones inside the VPK.

In other Valve games, you can even package sounds inside your own VPK file and the game will use those in preference to its own sound files.  I'm not sure if that works in Portal 2, though.

Comment: Okay, I think I get most of that. I downloaded the GCFScape program and I've located the files I'd like to replace. What do you mean by path? And should I be making a separate folder of my sounds somewhere?

Comment: @DT75 Well, if you looked, they'll be in directories inside the VPK.  You have to match that in the actual file system.